# Imprimir componentes de um array em ordem inversa

Tags: array, c++, declaração-de-variável

Escrevi um código para imprimir os componentes de um *array* em ordem inversa. Porém, ele só retorna 5 ou 6 números (no máximo), mesmo que eu tenha colocado mais números nele.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

    int i;
    int vet[i];

    cin >> i; /*Tamanho do array*/

    for(int t = 0; t<i; t++) /*Adiciona coisas no array*/
    {
        cin >> vet[t];
    }

    for(int f = i-1; f>=0; f--) /*Imprime o que tem dentro do array em ordem inversa*/
    {
        cout << vet[f] << " ";
    }

}
```

Será que falta alguma coisa?

Comment: Pode colocar a print de um exemplo? Me parece correto o código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe isso:

```
    int i;
    int vet[i];

    cin >> i; /*Tamanho do array*/
```

Ou seja, você declara o tamanho do array antes de ler esse tamanho. Deveria ser depois.

Tente fazer assim:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int tamanho;
    cin >> tamanho; /*Tamanho do array*/
    int vet[tamanho];

    for (int t = 0; t < tamanho; t++) /*Adiciona coisas no array*/
    {
        cin >> vet[t];
    }

    for (int f = tamanho - 1; f >= 0; f--) /*Imprime o que tem dentro do array em ordem inversa*/
    {
        cout << vet[f] << " ";
    }
}
```

Observe que renomeei a variável `i` para `tamanho`. Dar bons nomes às variáveis é importante.

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/UTZgTL)

Comment: kkkk Vou adotar esse costume!!! Valeu Victor!!!

Comment: @MiguelTeixeira Se a minha resposta te ajudou e não lhe resta mais nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como aceita ao clicar no "✅" à esquerda. Isso também marca a sua pergunta como respondida/solucionada. Se tiver ainda mais alguma dúvida, pode deixar um comentário. 

Answer (score 2):

O grande problema é que está declarando o *array* antes de saber qual é o tamanho desejado para ele. Então primeiro peça quantos elementos ele deve ter, depois declare com o tamanho informado.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i;
    cin >> i;
    int vet[i];
    for (int t = 0; t < i; t++) cin >> vet[t];
    for (int f = i - 1; f >= 0; f--) cout << vet[f] << " ";
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/EaR9rO). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wxfqkkfw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Array/Inverse.cpp).

Comment: Primeiro eu declarei uma variável com o nome "i", depois declarei um array com a "quantidade de elementos i". Então, teoricamente, quando eu não defino o "tamanho" de i, o array já reserva uma espécie de tamanho máximo que pode ter ao ser alocado na memória? Pois notei que o código funcionava até um determinado número de elementos, e ao ultrapassar essa quantidade, ou acontecia um erro ou ele imprimia na tela um numero menor do que i, de elementos (na ordem inversa).

Comment: Não, é pior, ele usa um lixo que está na memória como valor, pelo menos é assim em C/C++. Se rodar em condições diferentes o número mudará, é virtualmente aleatório.

Comment: Entendi!! Valeu Maniero!!!